# Exporting the HTML into their own html file with html-loader and extract-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-html-loader

I am trying to convert the html file that would contain absolute paths in src. I found a similar problem in the webpack documentation. I try to use html-loader with extract-loader but gets an error.

1. html file ->  simple.html
2. index js file :

   ```
   import plik from './simple.html'
   ```
3. webpack.config.js  -> [https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#export-into-html-files][1]
4. Module version ->

   ```
   "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
   "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
   "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
   "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
   "webpack": "^5.28.0"
   ```

ERROR:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-loader/lib/extractLoader.js):
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (3:88)
  1 | // Imports
  2 | import ___HTML_LOADER_GET_SOURCE_FROM_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/html-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js";
 3 | var ___HTML_LOADER_IMPORT_0___ = new URL("./assets/img/xxxxyyyyzzzzz.png", import.meta.url);

 Webpack can resolve **import.meta.url**
```

Someone has similar problem ??

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue is that [`extract-loader` is not maintained](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/107) and that [this is a bug with that loader](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/102).

Allegedly, [there is a solution](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/102#issuecomment-895558537), though it only generated a new issue for me:

Disable `esModule`s in the options for the `html-loader` that runs before `extract-loader`. In other words, if your config currently looks like this:

```js
const config = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    "extract-loader",
                    "html-loader",
                ]
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Make it look like this:

```js
const config = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    "extract-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This apparently has to do with `extract-loader` transforming modules with `babel-preset-env`, which is deprecated in favor of `@babel/preset-env` and doesn't recognize some of the newer syntax features (like ES modules).